# Trying to convert WORKING python program to C++ but wont work?

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to create a program that calculates the exact number of primes generated by N terms of the function N^2 + N + 41 = y

I have written the program perfectly in python and it works just as intended. I also am well versed in C++ syntax and i tried to recreate the same program in C++ however, it does something entirely different than i want. I have posted the .py code and the .cpp code below. Hopefully someone can figure out why the C++ version is not working.

To my knowledge I have properly converted my code but i cannot for the life of me determine what is wrong.

```
    def quad(n):
        func_val = (n**2) + n + 41
        return func_val

    def main():
        endProgram = False
        while (endProgram == False):
            total_primes = 0
            num_terms = int(input("Enter a number (-1 to exit)\n --> "))

            if num_terms == -1:
                endProgram = True
            else:
                for n in range(1, num_terms + 1):

                    isprime = True
                    y = quad(n)

                    for i in range (2, y//2):
                        if (y % i == 0):
                            isprime = False

                    if (isprime == True):
                        #print(n , ": ", y , "\n",sep='')
                        total_primes += 1

                print("Total primes in ", n, " terms: " ,total_primes,sep='')
                print("Total composites in ", n, " terms: "\
                      , num_terms - total_primes,"\n",sep='')



    main()
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int quad(int n) {
    int func_val = (n*n) + n + 41;
    return func_val;
}

int main() {

    int total_primes = 0;
    int num_terms;
    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> num_terms;

    for (int n = 1; n <= num_terms; n++) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        int y = quad(n);

        for (int i = 2; i <= y; i++) {
            if (y % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            cout << n << ": " << y << endl;
            total_primes += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Total primes: " << total_primes << endl;
    cout << "Total composites: " << (num_terms - total_primes) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to my knowledge both programs are far from being similar.... you ask only once in the C++ version but you ask in the body of the loop in the python version.  The main loop in one is defined by something you calculate in the middle of the loop while the C++ counterpart is doing a for loop for all values in a range.  You assume things very lazily, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python:

```
                for i in range (2, y//2):
                    if (y % i == 0):
                        isprime = False
```

C++:

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= y; i++) {
        if (y % i == 0)
            isPrime = false;
    }
```

The latter iterates `i` up to `y`, and `y%y` is 0.

Comment: An optimization you can add in the c++ version: `for (...; i*i<=y;...)`

Comment: It's equivalent to i <= sqrt(y)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
for (int i = 2; i <= y; i++) {
            if (y % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
        }
```

to

```
for (int i = 2; i < y; i++) {
            if (y % i == 0)
                isPrime = false;
        }
```

unfortunately you iterate up to  y and y is always divisible by y.